# Merging a branch into another using bitbucket GUI

Tags: bitbucket, git-merge, bitbucket-cloud

I am working on branch A and now want to merge all changes from branch B into A on the Bitbucket cloud. Does bitbucket provide any GUI tool for that or do I have to use any git command?

Comment: Create a PR and click Merge?